# Invert edge trajectory graphviz

Tags: graphviz

i am trying to graph a doubly linked circular list in .dot language but it does not display as i want. Both of the circular edges are under the nodes but i want 1 of them above

this is what i want:
[expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UeUn.png)

but i get this instead:
[given result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8PUc.png)

here is my .dot code: [https://dreampuf.github.io/GraphvizOnline/#digraph%20{%0A%20%20node[shape=record];%0A%20%20graph[pencolor=transparent];%0A%20%20rankdir=LR;%0A%20%20p1[label=%22{%3Cprev%3E|%3Cdata%3E%2012|%3Cnext%3E}%22];%0A%20%20p2[label=%22{%3Cprev%3E|%3Cdata%3E%2012|%3Cnext%3E}%22];%0A%20%20p3[label=%22{%3Cprev%3E|%3Cdata%3E%2012|%3Cnext%3E}%22];%0A%0A%0A%20%20%20%20p1:next%20-%3E%20p2:prev;%0A%20%20p2:next%20-%3E%20p3:prev;%0A%20%20p2:prev%20-%3E%20p1:next;%0A%20%20p3:prev%20-%3E%20p2:next;%0A%20%20%20%20edge[tailclip=false,dir=%22forward%22%20splines=%22compound%22%20constraint=%20%22false%22];%0A%20%0A%20%0Ap3:next%20-%3E%20p1:prev;%0A%0Ap1:prev%20-%3E%20p3:data;%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%0A}](https://dreampuf.github.io/GraphvizOnline/#digraph%20%7B%0A%20%20node%5Bshape=record%5D;%0A%20%20graph%5Bpencolor=transparent%5D;%0A%20%20rankdir=LR;%0A%20%20p1%5Blabel=%22%7B%3Cprev%3E%7C%3Cdata%3E%2012%7C%3Cnext%3E%7D%22%5D;%0A%20%20p2%5Blabel=%22%7B%3Cprev%3E%7C%3Cdata%3E%2012%7C%3Cnext%3E%7D%22%5D;%0A%20%20p3%5Blabel=%22%7B%3Cprev%3E%7C%3Cdata%3E%2012%7C%3Cnext%3E%7D%22%5D;%0A%0A%0A%20%20%20%20p1:next%20-%3E%20p2:prev;%0A%20%20p2:next%20-%3E%20p3:prev;%0A%20%20p2:prev%20-%3E%20p1:next;%0A%20%20p3:prev%20-%3E%20p2:next;%0A%20%20%20%20edge%5Btailclip=false,dir=%22forward%22%20splines=%22compound%22%20constraint=%20%22false%22%5D;%0A%20%0A%20%0Ap3:next%20-%3E%20p1:prev;%0A%0Ap1:prev%20-%3E%20p3:data;%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%7D)

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Main change was to add a **port** position (https://graphviz.org/docs/attr-types/portPos/) to the head & tail of the edge.  Also removed some unneeded bits.

```
 digraph {
  node[shape=record];
  graph[pencolor=transparent];
  rankdir=LR;
  
  p1[label="{<prev>|<data> 12|<next>}"];
  p2[label="{<prev>|<data> 12|<next>}"];
  p3[label="{<prev>|<data> 12|<next>}"];

  p1:next -> p2:prev;
  p2:next -> p3:prev;
  p2:prev -> p1:next;
  p3:prev -> p2:next;

  p1:prev:n -> p3:data:n;
//  edge[tailclip=false,dir="forward" splines="compound" constraint= "false"];
  p3:next -> p1:prev;    
}
```

Giving:
[image]